# Proving $R(n_1+1,n_2+1,\cdots,n_k+1) \leq{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k \choose n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k}$

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings, ramsey-theory

The following statement is a well-known lemma of Ramsey number.
$$R(m+1,n+1) \leq {m+n \choose m}$$

Now, I want to prove the improvement of the above statement:
$$R(n_1+1,n_2+1,\cdots,n_k+1) \leq{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_k \choose n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k}$$

I found some references mentioning it but they just used it as an obvious 'fact'.
I tried to use an induction on $k$ or use the following lemma,
$$R(p_1,\cdots,p_{c-1},p_c) \leq R(p_1,\cdots,R(p_{c-1},p_c))$$

but unfortunately, both strategies did not work well.
Would you help me?
Thanks.

Comment: The last lemma seems to rather be about hypergraph Ramsey numbers. For graphs, you get a recurrent bound which is exactly the multi-Pascal relation.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Hmm...I searched about hypergraph Ramsey number, but I am still walking among the fog. Can you explain more details?